# App not running after intent added: how to fix?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been trying to create an app which opens the data settings, via a intent. After watching tons of tutorials online, I made this code, which now will not run. Can anyone help?

I'm using the latest verison of android studio, on a java project. In mainactivity.java, "setComponent" is flagged as 'non-resolvable' by the program.

Java Code:

```
package com.example.datamaster;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(newComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

Xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

When attempting to run, the error message is "Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."
As  new and young coder, I really am confused on this.
Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: `newComponentName(...)` – You're missing a space between `new` and `ComponentName`.

Comment: @MikeM. M I'm still getting the error and the app won't boot. I think it's all because of setComponent. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, you have other errors, too, aside from the not resolved thing. `MainActivity` should not be `abstract`, so delete that. And all of that `Intent` code needs to be inside a method, not directly in the class. If you're trying to start that Settings page right when `MainActivity` starts, then move that into `onCreate()`, after the `setContentView()` call.

Comment: @MikeM. uh... Sorry, I'm extremely confused...

Comment: Look at the first code block in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20024254. That's how your setup should look. However, that's not going to guarantee that your app won't crash for another reason. Beyond that, though, you would be better off seeking out some tutorials and other beginners' material on the web. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not an interactive tutoring site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you mentioned you'r new and a younger coder.
Let me clear your confusion.
First you need to remove abstract keyword

```
package com.example.datamaster;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


}
```

and then you need to override *onCreate()* activity lifecycle methode after that your code will look like

```
    package com.example.datamaster;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           //your XML layout name
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//Button click to luanch settings data uses activity
            FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

you can add this in your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

add these lines in your values/styles folder

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

replace

```
@color/colorPrimary
       @color/colorPrimaryDark
       @color/colorAccent
```

these with your color name or color code like #cccccc

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PPtmkpP Thanks for the awnser, still though it will not run. Attsched above is the screenshot, hopefully it can help. Thanks

Comment: You need to either remove
 Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
and
 FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

or declare these two in your xml

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/D1BAvHP I'm really sorry for annoying you this much. it still wont run...

Comment: just added xml layout

Comment: Wohoo - New error message - we're getting somewhere (honest I am so sorry for wasting your time this much (meant to put error message here will do in a sec)
The error is:

Comment: Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\Username\AndroidStudioProjects\ScreenMaster6\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:10: error: resource style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay (aka com.example.screenmaster:style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay) not found.
pt 1 - pt 2 next post

Comment: C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\ScreenMaster6\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:15: error: resource style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay (aka com.example.screenmaster:style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay) not found.
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\ScreenMaster6\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:26: error: resource dimen/fab_margin (aka com.example.screenmaster:dimen/fab_margin) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Comment: I cant chat yet, because I don't have enough reputation. Could we chat on something like twitter possibly?

Comment: added one more file and "dimen/fab_margin" replace this with "16dp"

Comment: could you please direct the values/styles folder? (Im dumb im dumb)

Comment: oops app/src/main/res/values

Comment: *head hits desk* New error code is                Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Comment: OMG you have forgot tag in xml like "</" or ">" check it

Comment: Just give me something where i can chat

Comment: Twitter - @JJTHEDJRenders - I have discord, skype, and a couple of others